# Copy cells from one table column or named range to another, with new color, only if destination is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns, "New Name" and "Old Name" in a table. The Old Name column is always fully populated. If a different new name is needed, a value is in the New Name column but otherwise it is left empty. I need some VBA code that will check if the New Name cell is empty and if so copy the value of the Old Name field but color it dark red.

Example Sheet
[image]

As you can see it's using absolute references but I'd like to make it dynamic. 
As such, I'd like to use the proper table ranges or I could create a named range if needed.

I'd also like processing to be much faster as this can sometimes go several hundred rows.

See below for what I've come up with my limited VBA skills.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 4 To 204
   If Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
       If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
           Cells(i, 4).Value = Cells(i, 2)
           Cells(i, 4).Font.Color = RGB(128, 0, 0)
       End If
   Else
   End If
Next i
MsgBox ("DONE")
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `application.countblank` or `application.countif(..., "<>")` or even `application.match(Chr(42), ...` to count the range.

Comment: In your code you are using Column E for "New Name" , but in your screen-shot it's in Column D , so which one is it ?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and updated the code. (Code was from the actual sheet and not the example)

Comment: @JesseDunn see my answer below, you can update the entire code by just updating the `Const NewNameCol As String = "D"` to the column you need

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` speeds it up quite a bit.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Const NewNameCol As String = "D"
Const OldNameCol As String = "B"

'=======================================================       

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' Get last row number from "Old Name" column
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, OldNameCol).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 4 To LastRow
    If Range(NewNameCol & i).Value = "" Then
        If Range(OldNameCol & i).Value <> "" Then
            Range(NewNameCol & i).Value = Range(OldNameCol & i).Value
            Range(NewNameCol & i).Font.Color = RGB(128, 0, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "DONE"

End Sub
```

Comment: This works but doesn't solve the problem that if I move columns around in the table it will break if the code isn't updated to reflect the new column.

Comment: @JesseDunn you want to move the order of the columns ? only that ? or you will also thinking of changing the names of the columns ?

Comment: Both could happen.

Comment: @JesseDunn moving the colums I can handle using the `Find` function, but if you are planning on changing both the names and the location, how do you expect to find the cell? based on what ?

Comment: Seems like a named ranged might be the best option as it would update as things get moved around. I'm not sure how it behaves if more rows are added to the table though.

Comment: @JesseDunn this is the way I would use it in my code, I usualy plan ahead the structure of my Excel sheets before running to code. If I find myself having to modify, then I find it easily at the top of the module, changing 2 letters representing the columns

Comment: Unfortunately I'm am not the only person who will be modifying this file.